# ExecutorService for Runtime.exec in Spring Boot the right way

Tags: spring-boot, executorservice, runtime.exec

I want to use Java `ExecutorService` in a Spring Boot  application.
Multiple module of the application is called as `@Scheduled`.
This module calls a Process to get a result from an external application using `Runtime.exec`. The process is supposed to get a result which is processed by java

This method can be called as part of a Scheduled thread as well as part of a request and response which can be called 24/7 . Multiple instances of the method can be running at a time.

Is it optimum to use `ExecutorService` defined as a local variable like this or some other method is recommended.
The requirement is that Java should not be infinitely waiting to get a result. It should be timed out.
Here is the method called

```
public String getExternalInformation(String applicationPath, String command, int noOfTries)
{


    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    Future<String> future;
    boolean taskExecuted=false;
    int trialNumber=0;
    String response = "";
    while((!taskExecuted)&&(trialNumber<noOfTries))
    {
        trialNumber++;
        log.info("Starting Trial: "+trialNumber);
        future= executor.submit(new TestProcessTask(applicationPath,command));

        try {
                System.out.println("Started Information Fetching ");

            response=future.get(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            taskExecuted =true;

            } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            future.cancel(true);

                System.out.println("Timed out!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    executor.shutdownNow();
    return response;
}
```

The `call()` method of the TestProcessTask will call the `Runtime.exec`  and parse the returning `OutputStream`.

Comment: I would probably use a spring configured `TaskExecutor` instead (that saves you from creating and managing the `ExecutorService` and you have a shared instance which you can configure). You also have some retry logic in there, you might want to look at the the Spring Retry project for that (used by Spring Batch and Spring Integration) for retry behavior.

Comment: Already using a TaskExecutor for running the @Scheduled job. It is the scheduled job which is in turn calling this method to run a Process.

Comment: Will the above method cause any issues in Memory Overhead or resources? Since it is a local variable, I figured it is memory safe. I am doing this as a quick fix for an application. If it can cause any issues, I want to be sure of it.

Comment: You have a thread that is already async, creating another thread... Why? Looks like you are making it more complex as needed. You are stacking thread on thread... Why not simply put this in a method annotated with `@Async` and don't bother with the executor. All in all looks more complex then I would expect.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance. I have not worked with Async before. I have a thread that is Scheduled, called as "@"Scheduled(CRON time specified). It is not labeled as "@"Async.  It calls a Process directly, which I am planning to call through ExecutorService, so that any task can be cancelled after a TimeOut. Can future.cancel() and Timeout be done using Async annotation?  Also, could you explain with an example?

Comment: Have you actually read the spring documentation? The use of async and scheduled is explained in there.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented Async in Spring as suggested by M. Deinum
Using the same Future methods and got it working.,